# Make it easier to find questions that are about linear programming and *not* about integer programming

Tags: discussion

If you search [linear-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming), the top results are all about integer programming:

[image]

If you subtract [integer-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-programming), the top results are all about binary programming:

[image]

If you subtract [integer-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-programming) and [binary-variable](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-variable), the top results are all about mixed-integer programming:

[image]

You have to subtract [integer-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-programming) and [binary-variable](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binary-variable) *and* [mixed-integer-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-integer-programming) before you start to get results about straight-up LP (although I would argue that one or two of them are really MILP questions in disguise):

[image]

**How can we make it easier to find questions that are about linear programming itself,** in continuous variables, without extraneous questions about integrality and logic constraints?

Comment: How about creating a "Continuous-Linear-Programming" tag?

Comment: That would be one solution. I like mine better, however, because (IMO) it is easier to get people *not* to use a tag in the wrong place (for example, by writing "Don't use this tag for questions about IP unless the question is about continuous relaxations" in the tag description that pops up when you add the tag) that to get people *to* use a tag that they don't know about/haven't discovered (if I am writing a question about LP, I will definitely tag it with linear-programming but it may not occur to me to specify continuous).

Answer (score 5):

The [linear-programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming) tag should not be added to questions about IP and MILP. IPs and MILPs have linear objective functions and constraints by definition.

Comment: This is only my opinion about what should be done. I have posted it as an answer rather than including it in the question so as not to sway the discussion one way or another.

Comment: I concur (with the qualification that if the question includes specifics about continuous relaxations, the LP tag might be warranted). It will be a long slog to educate new users about not "over-tagging", but it's worth noting that users with a decent number of reputation points can both add and delete tags on questions from other users.